# What to do if you are in the workplace and you dont have a work?

Tags: work-environment

My work depends on my boss, I depend on her commands: no command, no work. How can I kill the time to pass 8hrs on duty. I am feeling unproductive everyday, like "What am I doing here. I am just sitting here, looking at my screen All day!" I work as an IMS Assistant  (Integrated Management System).

Comment: I learned C++11 and Python almost exclusively during such "no work" times.

Answer (score 3):

**You have IoT to do!**

You got a great opportunity. Don't miss it. Most of the time everyone will spend some period like this in their early stages of when they come to professional industry. Basically this is something usual for many of us.

Learn about some area which is in your field. You can plan like weekly. 
This week I'm going to learn about Node.js/concurrency in Java/ linux bash scripting/ etc.

Don't think that your boss is just paying for you to be 8 hours inside the office. He/She might intended you to grab some knowledge during this time period.